# Permission denied to access file on localhost (wordpress install)

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I am having a weird issues... i have installed Wordpress locally (I'm on Ubuntu) and I'm now having troubles accessign an image file... in css I have:

```
.sprites{ background:url("sprites.png") top left no-repeat; }
._r3_c5{ width:210px; height:204px; background-position:-10px -10px; }
```

When I try to do:

```
<div class="sprites _r3_c5">
</div>
```

I don't see anything.
If I then check my source, and try yo open the (broken) image in a new tab, I get this message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /current/alex/wp-content/themes/starkers/sprites.png on this server.
```

Would anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied inside /var/www/html when creating a website and it's files with the apache2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378664/permission-denied-inside-var-www-html-when-creating-a-website-and-its-files-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be directory permission issue, because you are trying fetch a file using http.

How about setting directory permission to 755 or 777?

Comment: Yes in the end i set it to 777 and it worked... still I can't get why i could access other files in that folder, like css and php, and couldn't access the image.

Comment: **777** - Read/Write/Execute by Everyone. So basically you are trying to access an image file on front end which needs Read access. Other php and css files are executed by server, hence they don't need **777** permission.

There can be another possibility, like if you are accessing static file with a relative url. You can always hit-n-try. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like permissions issues with the account in Ubuntu that is used by Apache for the web site (this is usually different than your user account). Check the owner, group and permissions for the file/folder and adjust as needed.

This is a link from the WordPress codex about security. http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress