# Permission denied inside /var/www/html when creating a website and it's files with the apache2 server

Tags: mysql, permissions, apache2, lamp, ubuntu-18.04

[image: screenshot from inside atom]
UPDATE** The screenshot is within atom, but when I navigate to the directory using the file explorer, and right click, the option to rename or create a new folder are restricted and I cannot click on them.

I just finished setting up the LAMP stack on my fresh UBUNTU 18.04 installation. I have everything working, the default /var/www/html/index.html page from Apache2 is being served on localhost, no port forwarding or any unique domain name, i just wanna run this on my network from my computer for now.

If there is a simple way to create multiple websites and easily choose which folder to serve than that's fine, but I want to serve just one website for now.

When I go to my /var/www/html folder and try to edit the index.html file it says permission denied. What do I need to do in order to work inside this directory for the remaining time that I am building the website. I am signed in as the root user on my system.

Also, if I do change permissions to allow me to work in this directory, what does it mean for people trying to access my server if it was available to the public. (RIGHT NOW JUST ON LOCALHOST).

Lemme know if you need more info or explanation thanks!

Comment: You're logged in as root and still get permission denied?

Comment: yup, that's correct. I also try to open it in my ATOM editor which is the one I will be working on my website in and it doesn't let me make edits.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
```

this works, it changes the owner to my user instead of root user. I still don't understand because my user already had sudo rights and all those permissions. It was the user I created during the ubuntu18.04 setup, so there shouldn't be an issue, or idk.

Comment: this works thanks

Comment: Works for me, 2022 on Ubuntu 20 on an instance running on AWS LightSail

Comment: Its also working for me shorter syntax    sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html

Comment: That didn't works for me, Ubuntu 22 @ localhost

Answer (score 14):

File ownership issues can be fixed at the command line by typing:

#### `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html -R`

One caveat from 
 [turnkeyLinux.com](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20131121/wordpress-ftp-and-update-issues):

> Changing file permissions is a trade off
>   (often increasing security reduces user-friendliness and/or
>   usability). For security 'best practice' only the folders that require
>   write access by the webserver should be owned by the webserver.
>   If your webserver has write access everywhere and your server
>   is compromised it makes it easier to hack your WordPress install) but
>   for ease of use giving the webserver ownership should resolve all your
>   issues...

This article on [Understanding File Permissions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/) was great, too.

Comment: would this be a temporary or a permanent solution? i want my browser to run html files as long as am working with those. is there way for permissions to get reset automatically next time every fresh browser launch, or every reboot/screen unlock?

Comment: OMG!!!  Opening execute to the WORLD is a HORRIBLE idea for a public-facing website!

Answer (score 5):

This will help you.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html
sudo gpasswd -a username www-data
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

Comment: Thanks. This spared me lots of grey hairs!  :-)

Comment: Works. This is the relevant answer.

Comment: Works fine -until your webserver is hacked and taken hostage for Bitcoin!

Answer (score 3):

The permission error is occurring because the folder does not have the rights and rights are reserved with different user. (you can inspect this by doing **ls -l folderName**)

The solution for your problem can be handled in different ways following are the few :

**WAY1:**

1. Find out who is running apache by running the command **apachectl
   -S**
2. Locate the user name (say www-data)
3. Change the ownership of your folder as **chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html** (this will allow only your apache
   to play with files)
4. Run the following command **ln -s /var/www/html /home/username/html** (this will create a soft link for your folder,
   where you can edit/delete/read which will reflect on your apache)

**WAY2:**

1. goto /var/www/
2. **sudo chown -R www-data:${USER} html**
   (Now both apache and your loged-in user will have rights to play with file).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not `root` *or* you don't have a permission on some things(folder,files..), know that your actions are limited.

Take folder as example:

- first of all verify permissions of your folder

  ```
  ==>ls -ld linkto/folder
  ```
- and after give it a permissions it need or type the command bellow to add all permissions

  ```
  ==>sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
  ```

verify permissions of your folder again if it is correct then try to copy again

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file as root. Or better yet fix your permissions so you don’t have to worry.

Comment: How do I change my permission the correct way? I know it's gotta do something with chmod, but I can't find the correct protocol for doing this.

Comment: Surely someone has setup the LAMP stack on their machine before, given there are millions of sites running it, why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just write

> [image: Blockquote]

And give read and write rights to the folder ( not user )

Answer (score 0):

Try the following the command

For Read and Write:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /var/www
```

For Read, Write and Execute:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

All solutions I find here either make the current user or `www-data` both owners and groups of the `html` directory, but it's much, much better to make the user the group and `www-data` the owner:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www
```

If not, applications which you don't completely control, like WordPress, won't be able to get sufficient permissionsto work