# How to get back permission to access my site inside /var/www/html/site_name

Tags: flask, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I've been trying to host my website on Ubuntu 20.04 using apache2 and I recently ran the following code to enable apache to read,write and execute `sudo chmod 467 -R /var/www/html/site_name` unfortunately I cannot access the directory again as I used to using `cd /var/www/html/site_name` as it returns a "Permission Denied" error. I was following instructions from this website [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-securely-deploy-flask-with-apache-in-a-linux-server-environment-7eacd4c69a73) and I messed up by using 467 instead of 464. This is my first time deploying  a website so I'm not quite sure of how I should go about it. I have further questions and I would really appreciate guidance from anyone  who has experience deploying a flask website on apache2 running on ubuntu 20.04. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/site_name` and now when I do `cd /var/www/html/site_name` I can access my site folder. I hope this helps someone as for the source of the answer I found it in this question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378664/permission-denied-inside-var-www-html-when-creating-a-website-and-its-files-wi).